# Set boundary ODE solver

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I'm solving differential equations using an `ODE15s` solver.
However with specific parameters the solution becomes unreal.
When you have a reaction like:

`A + B <--> C <--> D + E and E + F --> G`

The concentration of `A` and `E` becomes less than zero if I start with an high initial concentration of `F`. This is impossible in practice.

Is there a way that I can specify boundary conditions in the ODE solver?
For instance:

`If A<0 : A=0`

Comment: Have you tried setting the `NonNegative` option?  See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1016858

Comment: Also, it *might* help to tighten up the error tolerances (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1021204).  There's no guarantee it will help, but it might be enough to fix the problem in the cases you care about.

Comment: Thank you very much option NonNegative worked for me!